# How to expand a database in Sybase IQ?

Tags: sap-iq

I'm trying to import several tables into a Sybase IQ database. First, I run a script to create the tables, then I run another script to import the data with a set of LOAD TABLE statements.

The first script created the tables correctly (in the only dbspace of this database). When I run the import script, after importing half of the tables, I got a message saying that the dbspace was full.

So I created another dbspace and re-run the script from where it left off. However I'm still getting the error saying that the first dbspace is full. Why isn't Sybase IQ using the second dbspace that I created? I see that the tables are related to the first dbspace, but shouldn't a table expand to another dbspace as needed?

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell the database server that you want to put some of the tables into the second dbspace. You do this by adding the "IN " clause to the create table statement.

For example, `CREATE TABLE x (<cols>)` puts the table into the SYSTEM dbspace, since you didn't specify one. But `CREATE TABLE x (<cols>) IN mydbspace` puts it into the dbspace called "mydbspace".

Docs on the create table statement are [here](http://dcx.sap.com/index.html#sa160/en/dbreference/create-table-statement.html*d5e47959). Note that these are SQL Anywhere docs but since SQL Anywhere is the execution engine for IQ, they still apply.

*Disclosure: I work for SAP in SQL Anywhere engineering.*

Comment: What happens when the table grows? I need to add files to its dbspace? Can Sybase IQ add files to the dbspace automatically?

Comment: Each dbspace consists of exactly one file, which will automatically expand as needed until it runs out of disk space or hits the file system's file size limit.

Comment: [See this link](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00170.1510/html/iqapgv1/X316364.htm) It says that "A single dbspace can have multiple dbfiles."

Comment: OK, then that must specific to IQ. What I said is true for SQL Anywhere, which does not support the ALTER FILE statement referenced in that document.